# How to get the arithmetic squence of a array(C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

so my requirements are

- REQUIRES: n >= 1.  Elements a[0] ... a[n-1] exist.
- PROMISES

  - The return value is 1 if n == 1.
  - If n > 1, the return value is 1 if a[0] ... a[n-1] form
    an arithmetic sequence.
- PROMISES
  Otherwise, the return value is 0.

my function so far is

```
int is_arith_seq(const int *a, int n)
{
    assert(n >= 1);

    if (n == 1)
    return 1;
    int i;

    int initaldif = a[1]-a[0];
    int currentdif,result;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        currentdif = a[i+1]-a[i];
        if(initaldif!=currentdif)
            return 0;
    }
            return 1;

}
```

My code does not work,as I am completely stuck now, what can I do to correct it.

Comment: What is "does not work". What does the code do differently than what it has to do?

Comment: Also, isn't this the kind of assignment that you have to solve recursively.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<n;i++)` --> `for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)` otherwise you index outside the array bounds.

Comment: `if(initaldif!=currentdif)` if `a[i] = 0`, your test will produce an incorrect result.

Comment: the function shows some array elements correctly and some incorrectly idk why.

Comment: change `for (i=0;i<n;i++)`  to `for (i=1;i<n-1;i++)`. The computation when `i==0` is useless as it will be always true. And as @WeatherVane pointed out if the upper bound is `<n` rather than `<n-1` it will access elements outside array bounds

Comment: what would replacing if (initaldif!=currentdif) with if a[i] = 0 do

Comment: thanks, i figured out my mistake, this code is perfect but when i tested it i did something stupid

Comment: Perfect not! Please read the comments.

Comment: Something you need to learn early is that one of the many forms of "undefined behavior" is "trick the author into thinking they wrote correct code, and then start failing later when they least expect it". And in reality, this form of undefined behavior happens surprisingly often.

Comment: A better approach is to predict the next term in your sequence and test for it. `initaldif = a[1]-a[0];` then `a[2] = a[1] + initaldif` or `a[i] = a[i-1] + initaldif` or for your code `if (a[i] != a[i-1] + initaldif) return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If array has n elements your for loop will cause a segmentation fault. It goes all the way to `n-1` but you are accessing `a[i+1]`. `a[n]` is out of bounds. Modify like this :

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    currentdif = a[i+1]-a[i];
    if (initaldif != currentdif)
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here
 
   `currentdif = a[i+1]-a[i];`
What do you think will happen to this code during n-1 th iteration?
`i = n-1 + 1 = n`
Therefore the function either returns 1 if n=1 or returns 0 due to the error!

Answer (score 0):

Off-by-one errors are one of the most common programming mistakes. A good way to quickly track many of these down is to look at the very first and last iterations of your loops.

Your intent is that your loop computes the differences

```
a[1]-a[0]   a[2]-a[1]   ...   a[n-1]-a[n-2]
```

The first iteration has `i=0` and computes `a[1]-a[0]`, and the last iteration has `i=n-1` and computes `a[n]-a[n-1]`. Whoops, that's wrong! Need to adjust the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your arithmetic sequence test should set the `initialdif` as you have done, but then predict what the next element is throughout the sequence. If any term fails, the string of numbers is not an *arithmetic sequence*:

```
int initaldif = a[1]-a[0];

for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
    if (a[i] != a[i-1] + initaldif)
        return 0;

return 1;
```